# How can I place a decimal point in a hex representation of an integer?

Tags: c++, data-conversion

I have a value stored in a `short int` that only makes sense when represented as hexadecimal digits with a decimal point. To exemplify: if the `short int` contains 1132 decimal (534h), then I need to output "5.34". The value comes from a function hidden in a shared library from a company, so I have to accept what I'm given. The result *does not need to be a number type* (int or float); rather, it can be of any type (e.g. string) that I can feed into the standard output stream.

The given value in the `short int` will always be such that when represented as hexadecimal digits, all digits will be in the range 0–9 (never A–F). There should always be two decimal places.

I know I can represent the decimal digits as hex digits with `std::hex` and output "534" with `std::out`, but I don't know how to store those individual digits (5, 3, 4) in memory so I can insert a `.` in them.

Once I *do* get the hex digits, should I convert the set of hex digits to a string and place the decimal point three characters from the right? Or would it be easier to somehow convert to a floating point format and divide by 100 (64h)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int dodgy(char* buf, unsigned input) {
    return sprintf(buf, "%x.%02x", input/256, input&0xff);
}
string dodgy2(unsigned input) {
    char buf[(CHAR_BIT * sizeof input + 11)/4];
    dodgy(buf, input);
    return string(buf);
}
```

Comment: can you explain your buffer size calculation?

Comment: easy. `input` has `sizeof input` bytes, a byte has `CHAR_BIT` bits, 4 are needed for a whole hex digit, but there's no guarantee `CHAR_BIT * sizeof input` is divisable by 4, so add 3 first (standard unsigned int arithmetic rounds down). Now we need 1 char for `.` and one for `\0`, so add two more bytes.

Comment: @Cerran: You mean 4 bits (16 possible values) each, for a total of 8 bits (256 possible values).

Comment: @Deduplicator Even better would be `void dodgy(char* buf, unsigned& input)`, right? No need for a return value, and no need to copy `input`. Although having two separate functions isn't really necessary in the first place.

Comment: dodgy returns the length of the output string in the buffer. Parameter 2, the input number, is rather loosely related to it, so better don't use it as an inout param. With the last part you are certainly right: I only had two functions in the end, because i forgot to put it into a std::string.

Comment: I don't understand. The return value of `dodgy` is never used in the code, and `input` holds the same value in both functions.

Comment: Ah, you just didn't want to copy input? That's a pessimization, I don't think there are any implementations which have bigger int than int*. As well, any moderately modern compiler will inline for sure anyway.

Comment: This code works, at least for the few values I've tried so far. However, I think the buffer size is much larger than necessary. Would this make more sense: `char buf[sizeof input + 2]`, where 2 is for the extra `.` and `\0`? After also adjusting `unsigned` to match my true input type, this seems to create a character array without any unused elements.

Comment: better replace `unsigned` with `unsigned short` then. That way, if you ever forget you may only pass a short on pain of UB, the compiler knows. Anyway, it's a pretty pointless optimisation on desktops. Those 4 bytes just don't make enough difference.

Comment: Ok, it took me a while, but I finally figured out the logic behind your code. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Hex is a print representation, not a value type. It sounds like BCD to me, in which case it all makes sense. You just have to convert it to decimal, nibble-wise, i.e. 4 bits at a time, and insert the decimal point before the last two digits. There's plenty of BDC to ASCII code around, and it's not hard to figure out yourself. The important thing is to figure out what it actually is first.

Comment: After performing some bit-shifting, I can confirm that it's BCD. Thanks for the tip; thinking in terms of BCD didn't immediately come to my mind.

Comment: AFAICT, it should only be printed once, not processed any other way, so conversion into the standard format is not needed. Still, better to know what it is, and how to covert it in the general case. I should have remembered BCD too, but it is somewhat uncommon...